# Right to left an ADF page in jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am using oracle jdeveloper and adf and I made a (fusion web application (adf)) app .
Now my question is ..
how can I have a right to left page ? Or how to change alignment of a JSF/Facelets page to Right-To-Left ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please confirm which version of ADF you are currently using?

I believe you just need to add:

```
<right-to-left>true</right-to-left>
```

to your adf-faces-config.xml file, as per the [ADF Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28967/web_laf004.htm#sthref1640).

Answer (score 0):

This thread will talk more about how to make ADF Faces pages render right to left.[thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2335917&tstart=30).

Comment: Please [provide context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for the link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing you need in here is to make the language of the view tag of your jsp pages point to language of RTL behavior like Arabic for instance, this won't only make it right to left, but will internationalize all the strings of the components to suit your language needs

Answer (score 0):

change the default locale to "en"
in faces-config.xml .. application tab